# BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT in Retrofit 1.9

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm spending a lot of time with this and I don't know what really is happening.
I'm getting retrofit.RetrofitError: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Is a get method and notice that I'm using retrofit 1.9!!!

MY CALL:

```
RestServices.getArticlesToBuyMB(parameters, new retrofit.Callback <List<List<Products>>>() {
            @Override
            public void success(List<List<Products>> lists, Response response) {
            }


            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, error.toString());
            }
        });
```

PRODUCTS Model;

```
   @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("archive_thumbnail")
    @Expose
    private String archiveThumbnail;
    @SerializedName("price")
    @Expose
    private float price;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("brand_name")
    @Expose
    private String brandName;
```

PRODUCTRESPONSE

```
@SerializedName("products")
    @Expose
    private List<List<Products>> products = null;

    public List<List<Products>> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public void setProducts(List<List<Products>> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }
```

JSON

```
{
    "products": [
        [{
            "id": 210,
            "archive_thumbnail": "https:...",
            "price": null,
            "name": "this is my name 1",
            "brand_name": "brand name"
        }],
        [{
            "id": 202,
            "archive_thumbnail": "https://....",
            "price": null,
            "name": "this is my name 2",
            "brand_name": "brand name"
        }]
    ]
}
```

Comment: Products is an object, not an array in this context.  Changue your call back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your response like below because response is starting with JSON OBJECT not with JSON ARRAY.

```
RestServices.getArticlesToBuyMB(parameters, new retrofit.Callback < PRODUCTRESPONSE>() {
            @Override
            public void success(PRODUCTRESPONSE lists, Response response) {
            }


            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, error.toString());
            }
        });
```

Hope it will help you.